# Google AdSense is not showing because of invalid activity

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, accounts

I have a Google AdSense account that using account ***exxxxxx@gmail.com***

Google AdSense is working fine and I earned money.

I recreated another account ***mxxxxxxx@gmail.com*** and AdSense account. 
I violated the terms with invalid click.

My second account ***mxxxxxxx@gmail.com*** has been disabled but I still able to login my first account ***exxxxxx@gmail.com***

I can't display my Google AdSense ads with my first account ***exxxxxx@gmail.com***.
I tried send invalid appeal form to them. Here's there reply:

> we've noticed that your account has not been disabled for invalid
>   activity

Has my site has been blocked?
How do I check the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are [only allowed to have one Google AdSense account](http://www.matrudev.com/post/google-adsense-account-per-person/). Just having multiple accounts is a violation of the terms of service that can get your accounts shut down.

When you have invalid clicks on your account Google almost never allows you to re-active an account.  I'm afraid that you have burned your bridges with Google and will not be able to use AdSense services in the future.